# WordPress сайт грузит стили из файла кэша сайта

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть сайт на WordPress, есть админка. Захожу с админки, смотрю код элемента и вижу много тэгов  с подключением стилей: https://prnt.sc/syq0jf

Выхожу с админки, либо захожу в инкогнито, либо захожу в другой браузер, вижу, что стили в таком случае грузятся уже из одного файла: https://prnt.sc/syq1zq

Как мне обновить этот файл, чтобы изменения отображались и у пользователей?
Пробовал чистить кэш браузера, обновлял кэш сайта через WP Super Cache и ничего не помогло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отключите плагин Fast Velocity Minify или сбросьте его кеш в настройках.